# C Sprintf() appends junk characters

Tags: c, printf

I tried to use sprintf to append a int, string and an int.

```
sprintf(str,"%d:%s:%d",count-1,temp_str,start_id);
```

Here, the value of start_id is always the same. The value of temp_str which is a char * increases every time. I get correct output for some time and then my sprintf starts printing junk characters between temp_str and startid. So my str get corrupted.

Can anyone explain this behavior ?

example

at count 11

11:1:2:3:1:2:3:1:2:3:1:21:3:1:2:3:1:2:3:1:2:3:1:2:3:1:2:3:1:2:3:1:2:3:1:2:3:1:2:3:1:2:3:1:2:3:1:2:3:1:2:3:1:2:3:1:2:3:1:2:3:1:2:3:1:2:3:1:2:3:1:2:3:1:2:3:1:2:3:1:2:3:1:2:3:1:2:3:1:2

at count 8

8:1:2:3:1:2:3:1:2:3:1:21:3:1:2:3:1:2:3:1:2:3:1:2:3:1:2:3:1:2:3:1:2:3:1:2:3:1:2:3:1:2:3:1:2:3:1:2:3:1:2:3:1:2:3:1:2:3:1:2:3:1:2:3:1:2:3:1:2:3:1:2:3:1:2:3:1:2:3:1:2:3:1:2:3:1:2:3:1:2:3:1�:2

I don't understand why and how "�" is appended to the string

Comment: Post the definition of all your variables and some code. Maybe `str` is not high enough.

Comment: At least 99 % of the times you're using sprintf you should actually be using snprintf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1> try to  **memset your str buffer with 0 befor using sprintf**

2> The value of temp_str which is a char * increases every time 
what do u mean by this ?

this should be normal charachter pointer which will point some string and **that string should be null terminated** and tha  will be copied to str

3> the **total size by combing all three argument should not be exceed the size of str buffer**

Answer (score 4):

Either `temp_str` is not null-terminated at some point or you've blown the buffer for `str` and some other memory access is affecting it.

Without seeing the code, it's a little hard to tell but, if you double the size of `str` and the problem behaviour changes, then it's probably the latter.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the string `temp_str` isn't NUL-terminated.  You can either terminate it before the call to `sprintf`, or if you know the length you want to print, use the `%.*s` formatting operator like this:

```
int str_len = ...;     // Calculate length of temp_str
sprintf(str, "%d:%.*s:%d", count-1, str_len, temp_str, start_id);
```

Comment: Just make sure you don't calculate the length of `temp_str` with `strlen` :-)

Answer (score 0):

You are running off the end of temp_str.  Check your bounds and make sure it's null terminated. Stop incrementing sun you get to the end.